# Convert dd-mmm-yy to yyyy-mm-dd in big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to convert date of type 'dd-mmm-yy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format in big query

eg: 01-mar-15 to 2015-03-01

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%m-%b-%y", "01-mar-15") as parsed;
```

**Output:**

```
Row parsed  
1   2015-03-01
```